# How to run Firefox and Thunderbird with different GTK style?

Tags: manjaro, gtk3

I use Manjaro Cinammon with the best GTK style I ever seen called Vertex Maia Dark. But the Firefox search bar doesn't look good, and other themes doesn't change this element it depends on GTK style.

Question: Is it possible to run Firefox with a different GTK theme?

Comment: Do have a look at [gconf editor](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17249/how-do-i-use-the-gconf-editor).  Disclaimer: I do not use gnome or GTK.